# showing hide control in form collection while posting page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

i am having some control with validation.
i am hiding some control so that validation will skip for that controls using j query hide() method.
but when i am posting my page controls which are hide on page are available in form collection.
is there any property so that those controls which are hide do not come in form collection.

Thanks
Nishant Kumar

Answer (score 0):

All inputs are submitted in a form submit.

theres nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove them completely with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: could you tell me.how can i do that.
i tried hide() attr('disabled',true) and css display none.but control is available in form collection.

Comment: @NishantKumar `$('youinputs').remove();` :)